# Google coral kiosk mode with virtual keyboard

Tags: google-coral

Can i run on the [Google Coral devboad](https://coral.ai/products/dev-board/) a chromium in kiosk mode with a virtual keyboard ?

On this [exemple](https://github.com/tensorflow/minigo/blob/master/minigui/edgetpu/start_chromium.sh) they run a chromium with a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

MendelOs, the os on the dev board is just a derivative of Debian10 (buster).
After some research, I found how how to do it (prior I have no idea what kiosk mode is):

## update and install needed packages

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get -y install unclutter xorg chromium openbox lightdm locales
```

## add kiosk group and user

```
groupadd kiosk
user add -m kiosk -g kiosk -s /bin/bash
mkdir -p /home/kiosk/.config/openbox
chown -R kiosk:kiosk
```

## Tell lightdm to automatically starts with kiosk user

```
cat > /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf << EOF
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=kiosk
EOF
```

## Tell kiosk user to do this on start

```
cat > /home/kiosk/.config/openbox/autostart << EOF
#!/bin/bash

unclutter -idle 0.1 -grab -root &

while:
do
  chromium \
    --no-first-run \
    --start-maximized \
    --window-position=0,0 \
    --window-size=1024,768 \
    --disable \
    --disable-translate \
    --disable-infobars \
    --disable-suggestions-service \
    --disable-save-password-bubble \
    --disable-session-crashed-bubble \
    --incognito \
    --kiosk "https://google.com/"
  sleep 5
done &
EOF
```

Cheers